# select one value if it exists, another if not

Tags: mysql, not-exists

In this table:

```
|value_id|entity_type_id|attribute_id|store_id|entity_id|value
|9289729 |4             |62          |0       |765985   |default value
|9289730 |4             |62          |1       |765985   |value in spanish
|9289731 |4             |62          |2       |765985   |value in dutch
```

I need to get the value for the store_id (that can be 1, 2 or 3) or the default value (store_id = 0) if it doesn't exist.
And it has to be included in a larger query composed of several INNER JOINS, which looks like this so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `p2c`.`product_id`, `name_id`.`value` AS `name`, `short_description_id`.`value` AS `short_description` FROM `catalog_category_product` AS `p2c`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `status` ON p2c.product_id = status.entity_id AND status.value = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `visibility` ON p2c.product_id = visibility.entity_id AND visibility.value = 4
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `name_id` ON p2c.product_id = name_id.entity_id AND name_id.attribute_id = 60
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `short_description_id` ON p2c.product_id = short_description_id.entity_id AND short_description_id.attribute_id = 62
WHERE (category_id IN ('1224'))
```

So what I want is something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `p2c`.`product_id`, `name_id`.`value` AS `name`, `short_description_id`.`value` AS `short_description` FROM `catalog_category_product` AS `p2c`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `status` ON p2c.product_id = status.entity_id AND status.value = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `visibility` ON p2c.product_id = visibility.entity_id AND visibility.value = 4
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `name_id` ON p2c.product_id = name_id.entity_id AND name_id.attribute_id = 60
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `short_description_id` ON p2c.product_id = short_description_id.entity_id 
 AND short_description_id.attribute_id = 62
//start of not real mysql code
 AND ((short_description_id.store_id = 3) IF THERE IS A VALUE FOR THIS STORE_ID
      OR (short_description_id.store_id = 0) OTHERWISE)
//end of not real mysql code
WHERE (category_id IN ('1224'))
```

Oh, and I'm using Zend's mysql, if that matters.
Any ideas?

Comment: [Coalese()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to left join twice to catalog_product_entity_text. Once for ID 0 and another for ID 3 and then do a COALESCE in your select

```
SELECT
..
 COALESCE(`short_description_id`.`value` , `short_description_id_DEFAULT`.`value`) AS `short_description`
..
FROM 
...

     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `short_description_id` 
     ON p2c.product_id = short_description_id.entity_id 
         AND short_description_id.attribute_id = 62
         AND (short_description_id.store_id = 3)

     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `short_description_id_DEFAULT` 
     ON p2c.product_id = short_description_id.entity_id 
         AND short_description_id.attribute_id = 62
         AND (short_description_id.store_id = 0)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Conrad, I have a few tickets to take care of this morning and then I'll try your solution, I'll get back to you