# select company 2's value if exists, company 1's value if not

Tags: sql-server, join, set

Windows Server 2012, MS SQL Server

I know there's a set-based way to do this, but I can't figure out how to concisely phrase my question to get a useful google answer.

tblConfig

```
companyid  var          val
---------------------------------------------------------
1          fruit        orange
1          game         Monopoly
1          book         Joyland
1          actor        Ernest Thesiger
1          condiment    ketchup
2          fruit        apple
2          book         Revival
3          actor        Colin Clive
3          condiment    relish
3          fruit        kiwi
3          book         Tales From a Buick8
```

I would like to select company 2's values (or 3, or 4, or n...), plus company 1's values where 2 doesn't have one (order doesn't matter), as in:

```
2          fruit        apple
1          game         Monopoly
2          book         Revival
1          actor        Ernest Thesiger
1          condiment    ketchup
```

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438157/select-one-value-if-it-exists-another-if-not) and thought I could make it work, but it eludes me. I just end up with a list of all values in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a prioritization query.  In SQL Server, you can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by var
                                order by (case when companyid = 2 then 1
                                               when companyid = 1 then 2
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The logic for prioritization is in the `order by` clause for `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (companyid int,var varchar(50), val varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'fruit','orange'),
(1,'game','Monopoly'),
(1,'book','Joyland'),
(1,'actor','Ernest Thesiger'),
(1,'condiment','ketchup'),
(2,'fruit','apple'),
(2,'book','Revival'),
(3,'actor','Colin Clive'),
(3,'condiment','relish'),
(3,'fruit','kiwi'),
(3,'book','Tales From a Buick8')
```

---

```
;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By var order by companyid Desc)
     From  @YourTable
     Where companyid<=2
)
Select * from cteBase where RowNr=1
```

Returns

```
companyid   var         val             RowNr
1           actor       Ernest Thesiger 1
2           book        Revival         1
1           condiment   ketchup         1
2           fruit       apple           1
1           game        Monopoly        1
```