# SQL: Is there a better way than "COALESCE on two selects" to find the first non-null result in an OR clause?

Tags: sql, if-statement, coalesce

Let's say I have this table:

| ID | LANG | NAME | DEFAULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ENG | Cinderella | false |
| 1 | ENG | The Ash Bride | false |
| 1 | FRE | Cendrillon | true |
| 1 | GER | Aschenputtel | false |

("Ash bride" is just fabrication that the same ID can have several names in the same language)
The SQL query should return the name in the wanted language, if it doesn't exist, the default language.

So if the user's settings are in German (GER), a look-up of the book should return the title "Aschenputtel", but if the user settings are Spanish (SPA), they should return "Cendrillon".

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438157/select-one-value-if-it-exists-another-if-not) brings up the same issue, but the answer suggests a double join through the name list, one for "lang='[preferred]'" and one for the default value, with a `COALESCE` to find the first non-null result. I am worried this would cause performance issues if the names list is long (50,000+ entries), when there cannot be a primary key (as there can be many names per language), and the question is quite old, so wonder if there is a method more along the likes of

```
SELECT NAME WHERE ID=1 and (LANG='SPA' OR DEFAULT=true)
```

and return the **first non-null result of the OR-clause**. Ideally, something like:

```
(not functional)
SELECT COALESCE(SELECT NAME WHERE ID=1 and (LANG='SPA' OR DEFAULT=true));
```

would return

```
CENDRILLON
```

and

```
(not functional)
SELECT COALESCE(SELECT NAME WHERE ID=1 and (LANG='ENG' OR DEFAULT=true));
```

would return

```
CINDERELLA
THE ASH BRIDE
```

Any smooth way of having one SQL query that would yield the expected result, without doing a double join on a long list? Or is a coalesce on a double select the only answer?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Comment: I think I did? But I've edited the question to clarify this even further.

Answer (score 1):

You can order it in a way, that `'SPA'` comes before the default (if existing) and then limit the result to one record.

The exact syntax depends on the actual DBMS you use. So the following is just an illustration how it could look:

```
SELECT name
       FROM elbat
       WHERE lang = 'SPA'
              OR default
       ORDER BY CASE
                  WHEN lang = 'SPA' THEN
                    0
                  ELSE
                    1
                END
       LIMIT 1;
```

But I don't know, if this any more performant. Check the plans for information on that.

Comment: A, wonderful! Of course! I never thought of use of CASE in ORDER BY.
I am currently using MariaDB, but I'll try it out and see what it can bring.

Comment: Hm. Have a hard time getting this to work when I have more than one book title in the list (not just the ID 1, but several more, each with their own list of titles). I guess I'll have to nest the queries in some way.

Comment: @Zimeon: Depending on which DBMS you use, you can leverage the `row_number()` window function then. If you need help with that, you can post a new question. But make sure you tag the DBMS you use this time. And provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.